# Native datepicker on Chrome and fallback for IE/Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

Along with HTML5 came a new set of input types. One of these is `date` and in Chrome this input produces a nice native date picker like the one shown below.

[image: Datepicker]

It also provides native date pickers on mobile devices which is my main strong point for using the new input type.

However, on Firefox (23.0.1) and IE (10), a native date picker doesn't appear and the input is treated as a normal text input. It's in these cases I want to fall back to a Javascript date picker.

The site this is for runs AngularJS and the current datepicker plugin is [bootstrap-datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/). What's the easiest way for me to disable this plugin if the browser supports native date pickers? Do I just need to check if the browser supports the `date` input type and disable the plugin if that's the case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make <input type="date"> supported on all browsers? Any alternatives?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020950/how-to-make-input-type-date-supported-on-all-browsers-any-alternatives)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do an HTML5 feature check like so:

```
// Determine if this browser supports the date input type.
var dateSupported = (function() {
    var el = document.createElement('input'),
        invalidVal = 'foo'; // Any value that is not a date
    el.setAttribute('type','date');
    el.setAttribute('value', invalidVal);
    // A supported browser will modify this if it is a true date field
    return el.value !== invalidVal;
}());
```

Then only initialize the bootstrap datepicker if `!dateSupported`.

Comment: That's awesome. How can I remove this created element thought? I say at the end `var isSupported = el.value !== invalidVal; document.removeChild(el); return isSupported;`. So cahcing the result and try to remove, but this results in `NotFoundError: Node was not found`. I want to remove it because it's not needed any more, plus bootstrap's datepicker pops up the picker aligned to this phantom element instead of the real one.

Comment: Ok, now I'm saying a `delete el;`, so the picker doesn't popup for the phantom element.

Comment: Good thought but this answer will explain why that is unnecessary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847220/javascript-document-createelement-delete-domelement

Answer (score 1):

I did the feature check like this. It includes the check if the picker is needed at all.

```
if (
  $('input[type="date"]').length
  && $('input[type="date"]').get(0).type == "date") {

  // Load Fallback Date Picker
}
```